# How to backup all my data from a server?

Tags: backup, rsync

I need to backup all my data from a server (in 10 minutes), preferably keeping the symlinks.

Comment: I suppose that since you used `rsync` tag you know about rsync. You could also make a image of the disk with `dd`.

Comment: Have you tried rsync? Or cp? Why 10 minutes?

Comment: @terdon because the sysadmin will reboot and format the machine in 10 minutes

Comment: you sure you need **full** backup instead of just the basic?

Comment: @Braiam Ya, I know about, but I'm not familiar with syntax

Comment: Depending on how much data you have and where you are copying to, this could take much longer.

Comment: @Braiam Just my home directory

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553/easy-incremental-backups-to-an-external-hard-drive/

Comment: also related (probably even a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/9090817/1392758

Comment: @RSFalcon7 - it's just considered related when it's on another SE site, dup if it's within the same SE site.

Comment: @RSFalcon7 - I'm assuming you searched SE beforehand, I wasn't finding a comparable Q&A to yours, did you find any? This might be the one so you might want to to embellish it a bit more.

Comment: I did. That answer (and also the one I posted bellow) wasn't working for some reason (probably some confusion in the ssh config of the backup-host that I was using), and I had a very tiny time window. When I tried the reverse direction it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Done in the server with:

```
rsync -avx --progress ~ user@backup-host:~/backup
```

More info [here](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/rsync_backup_all_your_data_single_terminal_command).

Comment: I also like to add `--delete` otherwise the backup just grows with things you don't need anymore. Make sure to use that option with care!

Comment: I will dig into those (and other) options with more time, probably there are lots of option that could helped.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this script to get a systemwide backup from my server.

Notice the sudo in front of rsync to make sure groups, users and permissions are set properly.

Of cause downloading a complete server might take some time. You may want to change the folder by changing `serv:/` with `serv:/home/myuser/important/`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#setup
folder=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
mkdir $folder
cd $folder

#download
sudo rsync -aPuzh --exclude='/proc' --exclude='/dev' --exclude='/tmp' --exclude='/sys'  --exclude='*/.cache' serv:/ ./

#compress
sudo tar -czf "$folder.tar.gz" *
sudo mv "$folder.tar.gz" ../
cd ..

#delete original
sudo rm -rf "$folder"
```